# How can I use a dynamic format string with the format! macro?

Tags: string, format, rust, literals

I want to use the `format!` macro with a `String` as first argument, but because the macro expects a string literal, I am not able pass anything different to it.

I want to do this to dynamically add strings into the current string for use in a view engine. I'm open for suggestions if there might be a better way to do it.

```
let test = String::from("Test: {}");
let test2 = String::from("Not working!");
println!(test, test2);
```

What I actually want to achieve is the below example, where main.html contains `{content}`.

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    read_from_file_using_try(&mut buffer);

    println!(&buffer, content="content");
}

fn read_from_file_using_try(buffer: &mut String) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
    let mut file = try!(File::open("main.html"));
    try!(file.read_to_string(buffer));
    Ok(())
}
```

So I want to print the contents of main.html after I formatted it.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28333612/how-can-i-append-a-formatted-string-to-an-existing-string

Comment: @Shepmaster: not a duplicate; it’s the other way round: the format string is the dynamic bit in this question.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Short answer: it cannot be done.

---

Long answer: the `format!` macro (and its derivatives) requires a string literal, that is a string known at compilation-time. In exchange for this requirement, if the arguments provided do not match the format, a compilation error is raised.

---

What you are looking for is known as a template engine. A non-exhaustive list of Rust template engines in no particular order:

- [Handlebars](https://github.com/sunng87/handlebars-rust)
- [Rustache](https://github.com/rustache/rustache)
- [Maud](https://github.com/lambda-fairy/maud)
- [Horrorshow](https://github.com/Stebalien/horrorshow-rs)
- [fomat-macros](https://github.com/krdln/fomat-macros)
- ...

Template engines have different characteristics, and notably differ by the degree of validation occurring at compile-time or run-time and their flexibility (I seem to recall that Maud was very HTML-centric, for example). It's up to you to find the one most fitting for your use case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I'm gonna go with replace instead though as I'm doing this to learn rust and not for something specific.

Answer (score 13):

Check out the [strfmt](https://github.com/vitiral/strfmt) library, it is the closest I've found to do dynamic string formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at many crates, but the libraries were all very complex, compared to the simple `format!`. Trying to do more complicate stuff than really needed.

The only one working nearly as a replacement of `format!` was [dyn-fmt](https://crates.io/crates/dyn-fmt).