# How to randomly select a format string

Tags: random, rust, string-formatting

Sometimes there are many ways for a program to phrase a message containing a dynamic value to its users. For instance:

- "{} minutes remaining."
- "You need to finish in less than {} minutes."

Not all of the messages contain the value as a mere prefix or suffix. In a dynamic language, this would've seemed the logical task for string formatting.

For media where repetitiveness is undesirable (e.g. Slack channels) there are so many different phrasings that producing each final `String` to output using something like:

```
pub fn h(x: usize) -> String {
    rand::sample(rand::thread_rng(), vec![
        format!("{} minutes remain.", x),
        format!("Hurry up; only {} minutes left to finish.", x),
        format!("Haste advisable; time ends in {}.", x),
        /* (insert many more elements here) */
    ], 1).first().unwrap_or(format!("{}", x))
}
```

Would be:

- Tedious to author, with respect to typing out `format!(/*...*/, x)` each time.
- Wasteful of memory+clock-cycles as every single possibility is fully-generated before one is selected, discarding the others.

Is there any way to avoid these shortcomings?

Were it not for the compile-time evaluation of format strings, a function returning a randomly-selected `&'static str` (from a static slice) to pass into `format!`, would have been the preferred solution.

Comment: Related: [How can I use a dynamic format string with the format! macro?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32572486/155423).

Comment: Have you considered randomly generating a number and using a `match` to pick a string to format? It would avoid generating all the strings then throwing them away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust supports defining functions inside functions. We can build a slice of function pointers, have `rand::sample` pick one of them and then call the selected function.

```
extern crate rand;

use rand::Rng;

pub fn h(x: usize) -> String {
    fn f0(x: usize) -> String {
        format!("{} minutes remain.", x)
    }

    fn f1(x: usize) -> String {
        format!("Hurry up; only {} minutes left to finish.", x)
    }

    fn f2(x: usize) -> String {
        format!("Haste advisable; time ends in {}.", x)
    }

    let formats: &[fn(usize) -> String] = &[f0, f1, f2];
    (*rand::thread_rng().choose(formats).unwrap())(x)
}
```

This addresses the "wasteful" aspect of your original solution, but not the "tedious" aspect. We can reduce the amount of repetition by using a macro. Note that macros defined within a function are local to that function too! This macro is taking advantage from Rust's hygienic macros to define multiple functions named `f`, so that we don't need to supply a name for each function when using the macro.

```
extern crate rand;

use rand::Rng;

pub fn h(x: usize) -> String {
    macro_rules! messages {
        ($($fmtstr:tt,)*) => {
            &[$({
                fn f(x: usize) -> String {
                    format!($fmtstr, x)
                }
                f
            }),*]
        }
    }

    let formats: &[fn(usize) -> String] = messages!(
        "{} minutes remain.",
        "Hurry up; only {} minutes left to finish.",
        "Haste advisable; time ends in {}.",
    );
    (*rand::thread_rng().choose(formats).unwrap())(x)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion would be to use a match to avoid unnecessary computation and keep the code as compact as possible:

```
use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};

let mut rng = thread_rng();
let code: u8 = rng.gen_range(0, 5);
let time = 5;
let response = match code {
    0 => format!("Running out of time! {} seconds left", time),
    1 => format!("Quick! {} seconds left", time),
    2 => format!("Hurry, there are {} seconds left", time),
    3 => format!("Faster! {} seconds left", time),
    4 => format!("Only {} seconds left", time),
    _ => unreachable!()
};
```

([Playground link](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=69407d4b1d8b3a7acb220d71edd89378))

Admittedly, it's a little bit ugly to match numbers literally, but it's probably the shortest you can get it.

Comment: My maintainability concern would be the split of the number of choices in the `match` and the number in the `gen_range`.

Comment: Yeah, that's annoying but difficult to avoid. I tried to work around that by setting the upper bound to `max_choices` and replacing the irrefutable pattern with `n if n >= max_choices`, but the compiler isn't able to tell that it's exhaustive ([example of what I mean](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=de8cf938ebc0bb5571bc3b406324627a)).

Answer (score 3):

Creating multiple strings is straight-forward to avoid by using closures (or function pointers):

```
extern crate rand;

use rand::Rng;

pub fn h(x: usize) -> String {
    let messages: &[&Fn() -> String] = &[
        &|| format!("{} minutes remain.", x),
        &|| format!("Hurry up; only {} minutes left to finish.", x),
        &|| format!("Haste advisable; time ends in {}.", x),
    ];
    let default_message = || format!("{}", x);

    rand::thread_rng().choose(messages).unwrap_or(&&(&default_message as &Fn()->String))()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", h(1));
}
```

Notes:

1. `choose` instead of `sample` for one value.
2. No need for a `Vec`; an array should be fine.

That's unlikely to improve the "beautiful" aspect. Macros can remove the drudgery:

```
extern crate rand;

macro_rules! messages {
    {$default: expr, $($msg: expr,)*} => {
        use rand::Rng;

        let messages: &[&Fn() -> String] = &[
            $(&|| $msg),*
        ];
        let default_message = || $default;

        rand::thread_rng().choose(messages).unwrap_or(&&(&default_message as &Fn() -> String))()
    }
}

pub fn h(x: usize) -> String {
    messages! {
        format!("{}", x),
        format!("{} minutes remain.", x),
        format!("Hurry up; only {} minutes left to finish.", x),
        format!("Haste advisable; time ends in {}.", x),
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", h(1));
}
```

Notes:

1. The macro requires at least one argument; this will be used as the default message.