# Initialize new String in rust with {}

Tags: rust

When I try to initialize a String with the placeholder `{}` using the following:

```rust
let range_from: u32 = 1;
let range_to: u32 = 101;
let insert_message = String::new("Please input Your guess in the range from {} to {}.", range_from, range_to);
println!("{}", insert_message);
// snip
println!("{}", insert_message);
```

It throws the following Error:

> supplied 3 arguments
> |                          |
> |                          expected 1 argument

Comment: The macro [`format!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format.html) creates a String, you could use that (`format!("... {} ... {}", range_from, range_to)`).

Comment: Awesome @SebastianPalma, Your suggestion works. If You turn it into an answer i am happy to mark it as the solution :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`String::new` can't do that. You can use the `format!` macro, like this:

```
let insert_message = format!("Please input Your guess in the range from {} to {}.", range_from, range_to);
```

Or, as of Rust 1.58, you can also do it like this:

```
let insert_message = format!("Please input Your guess in the range from {range_from} to {range_to}.");
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70504075/15602349) for more.